# C++ SIGSEGV How to get stacktrace?

Tags: c++, memory-leaks, segmentation-fault

I have a C++ server application developped in C++. This application is multi-thread. In production environment, we have a lot of SIGSEGV signals occured.

I have to debug and correct this application.

Is there a way to Log in the handler of the signals the stackTrace in order to see where the problem occurs? Do I have to use external application such valgrind (I don't know if I can : the Valgrind site tell the application will run much slower...)?

Thanks for your help.

Best regards.

Mikaël PLOUHINEC

Comment: As far I know you have to write your own code to get the stacktrace, yes it is possible. I had seen one implementation long long time back coded in C. Why don't you check the `errno` variable to se what it is being set to ?

Comment: You can execute a simulation server with valgrind in order to find several memory leaks and incorrect memory accesses.
In real environments, you can debug your core dumped file with gdb.
At least, if problems subsist, attach a gdb instance to your process and ... wait until a sigsev is raised